# Unity string to binary converter output error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make a simple string to the binary converter in unity using C#. The code is converting it well but the problem I am getting is that when outputting, the output is only the last letter typed.
For example, when "**Hello**" is typed I want it to display

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
```

But I am only getting the **o** conversion which is `01101111`

Here is my code in unity c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputField textInput;
    InputField.SubmitEvent se;
    public Text output;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        textInput = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        se.AddListener(SubmitInput);
        textInput.onEndEdit = se;
    }

    private void SubmitInput(string arg0)
    {
        string currentText = output.text;
        string newtext = currentText + "\n" + arg0;

        foreach (char c in newtext)
            output.text = newtext + " in binary is " + "\n" + (Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));

        textInput.text = "";

        textInput.ActivateInputField();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the output.text every time you loop through a character in newtext.
Currently you are doing :

- output.text **=** newtext + " in binary is " + binary thing 1
- output.text **=** newtext + " in binary is " + binary thing 2

You should be using the **+=** operator, however this will create a string that prints 
:

- Hello in binary is "value for h" Hello in binary is "value for e"
  etc.

You should create a string variable that you add to for the binary value, and then add that to output.text *after* the foreach loop.

```
private void SubmitInput(string arg0)
{

    string currentText = output.text;
    string newtext = currentText + "\n" + arg0;

    string binaryText; //This string will contain the Binary Data

    foreach (char c in newtext)
        {
        binaryText += (Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')); //Add that character's binary data to the binary string
        }

    output.text = newtext + " in binary is " + "\n" + binaryText;//Print the binary string after the speicifed text

    textInput.text = "";

    textInput.ActivateInputField();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello your code works correctly for me, you are overwriting your data use: `output.text +=`

Also verify that your text field is multiline or try removing the 
`\n`

The BestFit option in the Text component can also help improve visualization

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output change your codes as follows:

```
string binaryText = "";
foreach (char c in newtext)
    binaryText += (Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')) + " ";

output.text = newtext + " in binary is " + "\n" + binaryText;
```

If you use `LINQ` you can simplify it:

```
var binaryText = string.Join(" ", newtext.ToList().Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```